# My blade engine ( switch case ) didnt work , but include and extends still work

Tags: codeigniter, laravel-blade

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

You can see my error in this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUUbp.png

> template.blade.php

```
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- global stylesheets -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{base_url('assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{base_url('assets/css/core.css')}}"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{base_url('assets/css/components.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{base_url('assets/css/colors.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- /global stylesheets -->
    <!-- Core JS files -->
    @yield('corejs')
    <!-- /Core JS files -->
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

> menu.blade.php

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="<?=base_url('assets/images/logo_light.png')?>" alt=""></a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs-block">
            <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mobile"><i class="icon-tree5"></i></a></li>
            <li><a class="sidebar-mobile-main-toggle"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify3"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-mobile">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="sidebar-control sidebar-main-toggle hidden-xs"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify3"></i></a></li>
        </ul>

        <p class="navbar-text">
            <span class="label bg-success">Online</span>
        </p>

        <p class="navbar-text">
            <span class="label"><i class="icon-coins">3.242 pts.</i></span>
        </p>

        <div class="navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <img src="<?=base_url('assets/images/placeholder.jpg')?>" alt="">
                        <span>{{$_nama}}</span>
                        <i class="caret"></i>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/myprofile/edit_profile')}}"><i class="icon-cog5"></i> Account settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/Logout')}}"><i class="icon-switch2"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /main navbar -->

<!-- main menu -->
@switch($_menu)

    @case('ketum')
        <!-- Page container -->
        <div class="page-container">

          <!-- Page content -->
          <div class="page-content">

            <!-- Main sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
              <div class="sidebar-content">

                <!-- User menu -->
                <div class="sidebar-user">
                  <div class="category-content">
                    <div class="media">
                      <a href="#" class="media-left"><img src="{{base_url('assets/images/placeholder.jpg')}}" class="img-circle img-sm" alt=""></a>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <span class="media-heading text-semibold">{{$_nama}} </span>
                        <div class="text-size-mini text-muted">
                          <i class="icon-crown text-size-small"></i> &nbsp;{{strtoupper($_pos)}}
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="media-right media-middle">
                        <ul class="icons-list">
                          <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-cog3"></i></a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /user menu -->


                <!-- Main navigation -->
                <div class="sidebar-category sidebar-category-visible">
                  <div class="category-content no-padding">
                    <ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">
                      <!-- Main -->
                      <li class="navigation-header"><span>Main Menu</span> <i class="icon-menu" title="Main pages"></i></li>
                      <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/index')}}"><i class="icon-home4"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="changelog.html"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span>My - Activities </a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-calendar"></i><span>Amalan Yaumiah</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-stack4"></i><span>Agenda Kegiatan</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-quill4"></i><span>Catatan Saya</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-users4"></i> <span>My - Mentoring</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/mymentoring/silabus_mentoring')}}"><i class="icon-book"></i><span>Silabus Mentoring</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/mymentoring/lihat_kelas')}}"><i class="icon-tree7"></i><span>Kelas Mentoring</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-people"></i> <span>My - Ukmki</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-users"></i><span>Anggota Saya</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-statistics"></i><span>Statistik  Anggota</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-accessibility"></i> <span>My - Profile</span></a></li>
                      <!-- /main -->
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /main navigation -->

              </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /main sidebar -->
    @break

    @case('mentoring')
        <!-- Page container -->
        <div class="page-container">

            <!-- Page content -->
            <div class="page-content">

                <!-- Main sidebar -->
                <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
                    <div class="sidebar-content">

                        <!-- User menu -->
                        <div class="sidebar-user">
                            <div class="category-content">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a href="#" class="media-left"><img src="{{base_url('assets/images/placeholder.jpg')}}" class="img-circle img-sm" alt=""></a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <span class="media-heading text-semibold">{{$_nama}} </span>
                                        <div class="text-size-mini text-muted">
                                            <i class="icon-rating3 text-size-small"></i> &nbsp;{{strtoupper($_pos)}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="media-right media-middle">
                                        <ul class="icons-list">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#"><i class="icon-cog3"></i></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /user menu -->


                        <!-- Main navigation -->
                        <div class="sidebar-category sidebar-category-visible">
                            <div class="category-content no-padding">
                                <ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">
                                    <!-- Main -->
                                    <li class="navigation-header"><span>Main Menu</span> <i class="icon-menu" title="Main pages"></i></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/index')}}"><i class="icon-home4"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="changelog.html"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span>My - Activities </a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-calendar"></i><span>Amalan Yaumiah</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-stack4"></i><span>Agenda Kegiatan</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-quill4"></i><span>Kas Saya</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-history"></i><span>History Saya</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-users4"></i> <span>My - Mentoring</span></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/mymentoring/silabus_mentoring')}}"><i class="icon-book"></i><span>Silabus Mentoring</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/mymentoring')}}"><i class="icon-tree7"></i><span>Kelas Mentoring</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="{{base_url('Superuser/myprofile')}}"><i class="icon-accessibility"></i> <span>My - Profile</span></a></li>
                                    <!-- /main -->
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /main navigation -->

                    </div>
                </div>
        <!-- /main sidebar -->
    @break
   @endswitch
```

> home.blade.php

@include('pengurus.main.menu')
@extends('pengurus.main.template')

@section('title')
Homepage
@endsection

@section('content')
this is my content
@endsection

Comment: Since Laravel 5.5 the ```@switch``` is built into the Blade.
i think you are using an older version of it.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because of your laravel version, but you can always try to use if-elseif-statement as alternative, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#if-statements
or (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures)

try run `php artisan --version` in your projects' root directory and check corresponding docs